# Long mysql varchar variable in bootstrap tooltip

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, css, twitter-bootstrap

Tooltip displays only the first word from variable containing mysql varchar(300) data. 
What am I doing wrong?

I am using bootstwatch js.

**css**

```
div.tooltip {
    max-width: 350px;
}
```

**php**

```
$data=para();
echo "<tr>".
       "<td>1</td>".
        "<td data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='right' title=".$data['tooltip']." data-original-title=".$data['tooltip'].">".$info['one']."</td>".
        "<td>".$infotwo."</td>".
      "</tr>";
```

Thanks so much, for any help.

EDIT: This is how I fetch results from mysql:

`function para(){
$dat=mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);
return ($dat)};`

Comment: How are you fetching and returning the MySQL data?
What does the `$data[]` array contain?

Comment: How do you get $data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing quotes around your attributes:

```
echo "<tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='right' title='".$data['tooltip']."' data-original-title='".$data['tooltip']."'>".$info['one']."</td>
        <td>".$infotwo."</td>
     </tr>";
```

Comment: Thanks man...that worked like a charm...how could I missed those qoutes...thanks again...